# agm-marker iconUrl change on click of marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to change the iconUrl of marker when it is clicked . I am using angular google maps. iconUrl I am  setting using my local assets folder and not from service API.

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let m of mapArrayList; let i = index" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(infowindow)"
    [latitude]="m.geometry.location.lat()" [longitude]="m.geometry.location.lng()" 
    [iconUrl] ="
      {
        url: './assets/images/car.svg',
        scaledSize: {
            width: 40,
            height: 60
        }
    }">
```

How can I change the above iconUrl when a marker is clicked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could have a property on your array objects to know which state your object has. You would need to update this property from `markerClick` event. I used `isClicked` property on this example.

In this case you could check which SVG is needed to be loaded.

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let m of mapArrayList; let i = index" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(infowindow)"
[latitude]="m.geometry.location.lat()" [longitude]="m.geometry.location.lng()" 
[iconUrl] ="
  {
    url: m.isClicked ? './assets/images/car.svg' : './assets/images/bike.svg',
    scaledSize: {
        width: 40,
        height: 60
    }
}">
```

Comment: I am using  google.maps.places.PlacesService and nearbySearch of this service returns the array of objects. Hence, its not possible for me to update it. Is there any way to add the property?

Comment: I have added a property to my existing array and with conditional operator was able to change the icons. Thank you!!

Comment: Could you please help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836624/how-to-change-icon-of-previously-clicked-marker-in-angular-google-maps