# How to add my location button in Google Maps using Angular google maps?

Tags: google-maps, location, angular-google-maps

[image]

I am using angular google maps to display maps and markers. Is it possible to show the icon in the bottom right corner of the map that on click of it shows the current location.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of mapArrayList; let i = index" 
    [latitude]="m.geometry.location.lat()" [longitude]="m.geometry.location.lng()" 
    >

  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Google Maps API v3 does not provide any *default control* for "show my location", so the only option would be implementing your own. But instead of creating it from scratch you could utilize a ready made control, e.g.  [`klokantech.GeolocationControl`](https://www.maptiler.com/maptilerlayer/)

Here is an instruction on how to integrate it into Angular 2+ application using [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-maps.com/):

1)load `maptilerlayer` library  by putting it into `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://cdn.klokantech.com/maptilerlayer/v1/index.js"></script>
```

or dynamically, for example using [`scriptjs` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs):

```
get('https://cdn.klokantech.com/maptilerlayer/v1/index.js', () => {

});
```

2)initialize `klokantech.GeolocationControl` in component:

app.component.html:

```
<agm-map #map [streetViewControl]=false [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" (mapReady)="mapLoad($event)">
</agm-map>
```

app.component.js

```
export class AppComponent {
  lat = -25.91;
  lng = 145.81;
  zoom = 4;

  protected mapLoad(map) {
    this.renderGeolocationControl(map);
  }

  renderGeolocationControl(map) {
    get('https://cdn.klokantech.com/maptilerlayer/v1/index.js', () => {
      const geoloccontrol = new klokantech.GeolocationControl(map, 18);
      console.log(geoloccontrol);
    });
  }

}
```

[Demo](https://angular-google-maps-demo-wxek6v.stackblitz.io/)

[Source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-wxek6v)

**Update**

In case if you prefer to load `https://cdn.klokantech.com/maptilerlayer/v1/index.js` dynamically, below is provided the instruction how to perform it via `scriptjs` package:

Install the package:

```
npm i scriptjs
```

and [type definitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/scriptjs) for `scriptjs`:

```
npm install --save @types/scriptjs
```

Then import `$script.get()` method:

```
import { get } from 'scriptjs';
```

and finally load library:

```
get('https://cdn.klokantech.com/maptilerlayer/v1/index.js', () => {
  const geoloccontrol = new klokantech.GeolocationControl(map, 18);
});
```

Comment: I have followed the above steps but I dont see the location icon .

Comment: Do i need to install anything for this ? I have installed npm install scriptjs as i was getting error . Anything else to be installed? The map is  loaded in localhost url. I have found that it works with https only. Is that an issue?

Comment: @Nancy, i forgot to mention, this control does not seem to work over HTTP, only HTTPS is supported

Comment: @Nancy, the answer has been updated (see Update section). In addition there is a link to [demo](https://angular-google-maps-demo-wxek6v.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you so much Vadim

Comment: I am facing a issue here. When i click the icon for the first time , it returns the current user location on map. Then when i try to navigate with mouse in any other place in the map, and then click the icon again , it doesnt return the current user location. The icon works only for the first time. Actually it take around 10 seconds to update the current location on second time click onwards. it doesnt return immediately.

Comment: Is there any way to return immediately even on second click onwards. Because of this issue, I feel the control works only partially fine.